# C# wpf weird repaint issue

Tags: wpf

I have experienced this intermittent issue with WPF.
Sometimes, when a Window is shown, it will have nothing except maybe a button visible. And after moving your mouse around and clicking on the window, the rest of it will become visible.
I don't know if this is an issue with WPF or maybe the UI library I am using.
Anyone has seen something like this?
Thank you.

Comment: I've seen this in complex WPF app such as visual studio, but not on any WPF app I made. Can you please give more details about your 'library' ? Can you also provide more details on you code (especially the XAML and code behind) ? Are you using MVVM pattern ?

Comment: So what is the cause of that if it happens to complext WPF app. It is third party UI library we purchased that provides Ribbon and docking, etc support. I cannot be sure that it is to be blamed.